# How to get HTTP request body with webview2

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

I am trying to create a windows desktop application with browsing using webview2, using [microdsoft's sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf) as a reference.

I want to get the Body data of the HTTP request sent by webview2 browsing, but I can't get it. (I was able to get the request header and request URL).

How can I get the body data?

```
namespace WPFSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webView.NavigationStarting += EnsureHttps;
        }

        void EnsureHttps(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs args)
        {
            String uri = args.Uri; //get request url
            CoreWebView2HttpRequestHeaders headers = args.RequestHeaders //get request headers
            //// how to get request body? ////
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? And why is that method named `Ensure Https` ? What is the *real* problem you want to solve? The event is called `NavigationStating` the request has just started and may take a *long* time to complete. Some types of requests, eg WebSockets, SignalR etc, may stay active for a *long* time exchanging data with the server.

Comment: Intercepting and inspecting requests and responses is typically the job of a proxy. Whether you need one or not depends on the actual problem you want to solve.

Comment: Maybe you could use `CoreWebView2.WebResourceRequested` and configure the view to intercept the request via `AddWebResourceRequested()` and a wildcard (`*`). Seems like this could work.